# ruby multiprocessing - calling a function

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to pass an array to a function and run the function against each member of the array in parallel rather than iterating over the members.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I successfully used process.spawn, but this requires opening a new shell.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `Thread` (see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Thread.html)

For example:

```
threads = []
your_array.each do |item|
  threads << Thread.new do
    # do operation on item. Each one is handled in a new thread
  end
end
threads.map(&:join)  # wait for all threads to finish
```

---

It is worth bearing in mind the overhead of spawning new threads. If your array is very large, you may be better off taking *n* items at a time (e.g. with `each_cons`. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), and getting each thread to process a small batch, rather than individual items.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you of [spawnling](https://rubygems.org/gems/spawnling/versions/2.1.6) ruby gem. This provides the option to **fork** (to multiple processs) or **thread** (to multiple threads) the task.

If you want to achieve parallel execution with threading then use (Number threads we can open is limited by connection available to rails application):

```
threads = []
your_array.each do |item|
  Spawnling.new(:method => :thread) do
    #something
  end
end
```

Else to achieve parallel execution with multiple processes then use (Number forks we can open is limited by resourse available in serves where application running) :

```
threads = []
your_array.each do |item|
  Spawnling.new(:method => :fork) do
    #something
  end
end
```

Documentation of gem is [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/spawnling/2.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a new thread for each array. I would create one for each processor on the system (or possibly fewer if you want to be nice) and then allocate the work among them.

```
number_of_threads = 4 
items_per_thread  = work_items_array.length.fdiv(number_of_threads).ceil
work_items.each_slice(items_per_thread) do |items|
  Thread.new do
    items.each do |item|
      process_item(item)
    end 
  end
end
```

This works well if the items all take close to the same time to execute. If they don't then you can land up with a situation where one thread finishes long before another thread. In this case you probably want to create a queue of items and have each thread pull an item off of the queue to work on. You will need a thread safe Queue implementation such as the one Ruby provides.

Something like:

```
queue = Queue.new
work_items.each { |item| queue << item }
number_of_threads.times do |i|
  Thread.new do 
    begin 
      while item=queue.pop(true) do
        process_item(item)          
      end  
    rescue ThreadError
      # thread is empty 
    end
  end 
end
```

This also has the advantage that you can add items to the queue after processing has started.